# Is there any way to recover a deleted Minecraft save file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I accidentally deleted my Minecraft save file and I want to get it back. 
I have heard that if you right click on the saves, and click properties you can get your save folder back but I don't see any way of getting my save back from that. I have got to this stage but can't find the recover option for the file. Can someone help?

Comment: Well, depending on the OS, filesystem and partition-scheme...there's a very good chance that it is already lost. Otherwise you should ask this on SuperUser...but beware, there are already *many* duplicates there which handle recovering deleted files.

Comment: The right-click thing sounds like a way to access backups. Unless you already had backups being made automatically, there's nothing to recover.

Comment: "How do I recover deleted files" is not a game-specific question. Therefore, this question is off-topic on Arqade.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a computer-related question not specific to video games. It is better suited at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this website](http://lifehacker.com/393084/how-to-recover-deleted-files-with-free-software/how-to-recover-deleted-files-with-free-software) which gives you instructions on programs that can help you find deleted files. When you delete a file, it isn't deleted, it is still on the disk until another file is placed where it used to be, so try not to create many new files before you try to restore the deleted ones.

**Edit 1:**

Also Check out [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/449550/how-do-i-recover-or-undelete-files-that-i-accidentally-deleted) which is related to your question.

Comment: `When you delete a file, it isn't deleted, it is still on the disk until another file is placed where it used to be...` That's not completely true for all filesystems, just saying.

Comment: Do you have any examples? All of the file systems that come to mind just delete the file from its index instead of replacing its location on the disk with zeros.

Comment: [ext3 (and I'd also assume ext4) f.e. does not only mark the space as free, but overwrites all pointers to the file with zeros](http://batleth.sapienti-sat.org/projects/FAQs/ext3-faq.html#undelete). So you lose all information on the whereabout of the file, and if the file was fragmented, you have no clue where on the disk the rest of the file is even if you find the header information. I also thought that ext3 would overwrite the file header, but can't find any reference for that. On second thought, my claim might be a little bit bold, but I don't know that ext4 does with discard enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, just click properties and click restore previous versions and choose the date it was deleted. Or, if that does not work, go to Start and search system restore,

Answer (score -1):

You can use System Restore(Windows) or Time Machine(mac) to recover your files.